How do I insert data on DELETE into a different database?
My table holds material details in Material.db. Once the material is processed its details are deleted and new material details inserted. Before deleting I want this data stored in archive database archive.db.
How can this be achieved using triggers? To avoid changing my application I want an SQLite solution but I don't know if a trigger can insert into a different database.

Consider adding an isdeleted column instead.

Triggers normally cannot do what you want, but temporary triggers can. You can have connections that delete from the table(s) you want archived attach the archive database, then create a temporary trigger like:
CREATE TEMP TRIGGER name AFTER DELETE ON original_table BEGIN
INSERT INTO archive_table VALUES (old.column_name1, old.column_name2, etc.);
END;

The archive table reference in the trigger cannot be a fully qualified table name (like attached_db.archive_table), and the trigger needs to be created every time the database is opened (unlike regular triggers).
